# Tizen Mobile & IPad Linux - Does it allow GCC and Java?

Tags: java, c, linux, gcc, tizen

https://www.tizen.org/ Tizen Mobile & IPad Linux very exciting.

- Its allowing GCC. But does it run Dalvik JVM or OpenJDK?
- Will then it will be compatible with 32-bit or 64-bit compilers? 
  Or we need to convert our source to be re-compiled using ARM compilers? of GCC?

Will it be easier to port C, Java code's now to Tizen? Where its complex and not natively available under Android phones/platforms?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to ask them. ;)

Comment: LOL. Its a great platform, samsung powered. All i want a mobile which arrives with full Linux compatible, not hidden Linux like Android did. Not a platform where everything is completely new and re-inventing. :-)

Comment: And if you have any luck, I would buy one as well. ;)

Comment: It doesn't run Dalvik, it's not Android.  From what I understand they mostly want you to build HTML5 apps, unsure if they provide a Java VM or have native tools.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it will be possible to package applications as DEB or RPM packages, you will be able to include an embedded VM (for example Avian VM) if you want, probably no JVM will be installed by default. JavaSE Embedded and OpenJDK should work (maybe with small modifications) under Tizen even though the documention only mentions C/C++ for native apps and HTML5/JavaScript for web apps. Moreover, there is no Java binding to its native APIs yet except those already available for Linux ARM and for APIs supported in any Linux distribution (for example JOGL 2.0). If you really need some help to use Java under Tizen, please contact the JogAmp Foundation [here](http://jogamp.org/). Xerxes already succeeded in running JOGL 2.0 under Meego as you can see [here](http://labb.zafena.se/?p=532), why not doing the same thing under Tizen?

N.B: Don't expect official Java support under Tizen.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this two presentation from May:
[Tips and Tricks: Designing Low-Power Native and Web Apps](http://download.tizen.org/misc/media/conference2012/tuesday/seacliff/2012-05-08-1330-1410-tips_and_tricks-_designing_low-power_native_and_web_apps.pdf) on page 3.
and this 
[Implementation of Standard Accessibility APIs for Tizen](http://download.tizen.org/misc/media/conference2012/tuesday/ballroom-c/2012-05-08-1330-1410-implementation_of_standard_accessibility_apis_for_tizen.pdf) on page 9.

You see that basically Tizen will have two APIs and hence two types of applications:

- Native;
- Web(HTML5) pretty well documented already.

So no JVM or OpenJDK, don't know the Native API apps binaries will be compiled to but probably will know soon.

Since Tizen is pretty much in development you can check from time to time the official site.